# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « mou, flétri, éreinté » avec « flou » ?

Tags: étymologie

Je n'ai pas cité [la version française](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/flou) car elle ne propose qu'une étymologie. [La v. anglaise:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flou#Etymology)

> #### Etymology
>
> [Conjecture 1:] [1.5] From Middle French flou,
>   [1.4] from Old French flou, flo (“soft, wilted, tired, exhausted”),
>   [1.3] from Old Frankish *hlāo (“lukewarm, tepid, mild”),
>   [1.2] from Proto-Germanic *hlēwaz (“warm, lukewarm”),
>   [1.1] from Proto-Indo-European *ḱlēw- (“to be warm or hot”). More at lew.
>
> [Conjecture 2:]  Alternative etymology derives Old French flou, flo from Latin flavus (“yellow”), though the semantics is difficult to trace.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Adjective
>
> **flou** (feminine singular floue, masculine plural flous, feminine plural floues)
>
> 1. fuzzy; blurred, blurry; unclear

Comment les acceptions dans 1.4 ont-elles glissé à 1 ?

Comment: On dirait que 1.3 → 1.4 est un glissement également intéressant.

Comment: Quant à 1.4 → 1.5, pour l'instant je note seulement qu'en anglais au moins, « in focus : sharp :: blurry : soft », exemple peut-être de la relation entre « soft » et  « flou ».

Comment: Il me semble qu'il y ait confusion de langues ici. On ne peut pas faire des analyses comme ça. En mélangeant deux langues....Il faut deux langues séparées ou bien la traduction dans un sens ou dans l'autre. Les Canadiens souffrent d'une condition que j'appelle la bi-directionalité, qui n'existe pas. C'est un truc imaginaire que de croire qu'on peut arriver à trouver une équivalence entre les deux langues. La traduction se fait toujours dans **un sens** avec perte ou addition des éléments linguistiques....

Comment: @Lambie Tu as raison, la comparaison n'est pas très concluante. L'hypothèse que je voulais faire est qu'il y aurait une relation sémantique sous-jacente entre les deux concepts, mais il faudrait plus qu'une seule autre langue pour supposer cela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TLFi goes with the later etymology](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/flou) with the presumption that *flavus* already had "tired" as secondary meaning (*flavescere*, "wilt").

As far as I understand the etymological discussions (which I always find hard to do in the TLFi), the shift from "soft, wilted" to "blurry" may have come through the visual arts, where *flou* became some sort of technical term at some point (TLFi cites 1676) to describe soft shifts in color (i.e. *dégradés*). From there the shift in sense to "blurry" is pretty easy to achieve, and from the visual to the metaphor of blurry ideas is straightforward and seems to have been achieved by the time of Diderot, judging by the quote.